# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 when starting my app with nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I'm very new to Node.js and I installed `nodemon` globally, but while when I start my app with `npm start` command in terminal I do get the message:

```
vinnytwice@Vinnys-iMac fixit_server_node % npm start

> fixit_server_node@1.0.0 start
> node server.js

App executing to port  3000
```

while if I use the command `nodemon start` in terminal I get:

```
vinnytwice@Vinnys-iMac fixit_server_node % nodemon start
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node start index.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

not showing any execution on any port, and in fact when hitting an endpoint I get `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000`.
If instead I start it with the command `nodemon server.js` then it does work.

Why `npm start` fired the `server.js` file and `nodemon start` doesn't? Is there something I shaven't set properly?

Answer (score 0):

`nodemon` isn't a replacement of `npm`, they are totally different.
You can crudely think of `nodemon` being a drop in for `node`.

> nodemon is a replacement wrapper for node. To use nodemon, replace the word node on the command line when executing your script.

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Hence if your npm script has,

```
"start": "node server.js"
```

Add another npm script,

```
"dev": "nodemon server.js"
```

You would want to use `npm start` in production environment and use `npm run dev` in development environment

You are seeing the `ECONNREFUSED` error because in your `package.json` there is a field,

```
"main": "index.js"
```

when you execute `nodemon start`, nodemon picks up this value and it actually runs `node start index.js` as shown in your logs.

> If no script is given, nodemon will test for a package.json file and if found, will run the file associated with the main property

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Your `index.js` doesn't setup the server and hence when you try to access `127.0.0.1:3000` to hit your endpoints nothing is running there and hence you get `ECONNREFUSED` error

Comment: Right, indeed `"main": "index.js"` is in the `package.json` file. Dough  I don't understand why `npm start` reads the server.js file.. where do I find the npm scripts?

Comment: @Vincenzo It's in ```package.json``` under ``scripts```. Please refer the docs, https://docs.npmjs.com/

Comment: I see. If you don't have ```scripts``` and run ```npm start```, it will by default execute ```node server.js```. Check this, https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-start

Answer (score 0):

Notice this line

```
starting `node start index.js`
```

The output of your command `nodemon start` states that the file `index.js` is executed instead of `server.js`. You need to check your `package.json` file to see what is the main file of the program.

From the npm page of nodemon [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

> If you have a package.json file for your app, you can omit the main
> script entirely and nodemon will read the package.json for the main
> property and use that value as the app.
>
> nodemon will also search for the scripts.start property in
> package.json (as of nodemon 1.1.x).